# How to MATCH and CREATE a node and relationship?

Tags: neo4j

Learning Neo4j and need help with getting the basics right.  I am trying to find a Matching candidate then create a company and create a relationship between candidate and the newly created company. So, my query is

```
MATCH (b:Candidate {name:'Bala'}), CREATE (e:Employer {name:'Yahoo'}),
CREATE (b)-[:WORKED_IN]->(e)
RETURN b,e;

Invalid input '(': expected whitespace, comment, '=', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, ',', USING, WHERE, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input...
```

I am using 2.2.5 console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the two commas before `CREATE`. The clauses in Cypher are not comma separated, only elements within a clause are. Your query will read

```
MATCH (b:Candidate {name:'Bala'})
CREATE (e:Employer {name:'Yahoo'})
CREATE (b)-[:WORKED_IN]->(e) 
RETURN b,e;
```